# Javascript Image Properties incorrect under Webkit

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, webkit

I can’t seem to access individual DOM properties of an Image element in WebKit.

On my page’s script, `Document.getElementById("xvz")` returns an image element.

I see it in the WebKit console with:

```
console.dir(document.getElementById("xyz"));
```

It even confirms that the object is loaded and has a correct size, with the `"complete"` set to `"true"` and other properties valid.

Now, when I add into the script `console.info(document.getElementById("xyz").complete);`

it returns `false`.

And I check other properties, such as `clientWidth` and so on, and they’re incorrect as well.

This only happens when I access the individual properties in WebKit.  It doesn’t happen when I access the IMG document element and show ALL the properties in the console.

Additionally, Firefox displays correct behavior.

Even if I assign the element to another variable, I can list all the properties correctly, but I can’t access the individual properties.  What the??!

Anyone else see this?

Comment: Could you post a [small example](http://sscce.org/)? You can use http://jsfiddle.net for this.

Comment: I'm assuming it's a typo when entering the question here, but you've got both `getElementById("xvz")` and `getElementById("xyz")` in your question.

Comment: Are you using the same "id" value for more than one element? What does `console.log(typeof document.getElementById('xyz'))` say?

Comment: [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/as8qX/1/) example demonstrating WebKit's ability to not do what you describe. (That is, it works fine.)